# What is B2B integration?

Tags: integration, b2b

What would it say to do a B2B integration? I'm looking for work and some list that's what they are doing, typical a it-consulting firm does this kind of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is vague because B2B has been co-opted by so many marketing campaigns. Business-2-Business integration means data flow across the corporate firewall. Anything currently done by hand and by mail can eventually be automated. Successful examples of B2B include web site traffic that takes that place